# ENO-Runge-Kutta discretization

Tags: finite-difference, runge-kutta, weno

One beginner's question about **discretization** of a Hamilton-Jacobi equation(non-linear)
$$
u_t = H(u_x)
$$

$u_x$ is discreated with 2nd order ENO-FD

1st order: $D_1^{\pm}u =  \pm [u_{x\pm1} - u_x ] / \Delta_x$

2nd order:
$$D_2^{\pm}u =  D_1^{\pm}u \mp \frac 1 2  \Delta x \{\min[ \max (D_1^{\pm}D_1^{\pm}u,0),\max(D_1^{-}D_1^{+}u,0)] +\\
\max[ \min (D_1^{\pm}D_1^{\pm}u,0),\min(D_1^{-}D_1^{+}u,0)] \} 
$$
and  $n$th order flux $\hat D^n_x u=\max(|\max(D^{-,n}_xu,0)|,|\min(D^{+,n}_xu,0)|)$

while $u_t$ is discreated with 2nd Order ENO-Runge-Kutta
$$
\delta_1 u = \Delta t H (\hat D_x u) \\
\delta_2 u= \frac {1} {2} (\delta_1u+ \Delta t H (\hat D_x (u + \delta_1 u)) \\
$$
It seems $x=u + \delta_1 u$ in flux $\hat D_x$ is not located at any grid point in stencil?  And how to calculate $\hat D_x(u+\delta_1u)$?

Comment: How are you discretizing $H(u_x)$ so that values are not returned on the same grid? Almost every finite difference method is constructed in this way.

Comment: $D_x^{\pm} = \pm[{u_{x\pm1}-} u_x]/{\Delta x} $ and $\hat D_x u = \max(|\max(D_x^-u,0)|, |\min(D^+_xu, 0)| )$ 

spatial grid discretizing with same$\Delta x$, $[x_i, x_i+\Delta x]$.

Comment: Where did you come up with $x=u+δ_1u$? On the left side you have the fixed grid coordinates, on the right a different function on the grid that evolves dynamically.  It might help to once write all formulas with all arguments, starting with $u=u(x,t)$. // Is it intentional that there are no negative values in the ENO-FD, even if the function is falling?

Comment: That's right, I just need to calculate right hand side to update soultion. This item $u+\delta x$ confused me.